# Ubuntu screen breaks randomly

Tags: gnome, screen, 20.10

https://filebin.net/4ahdozzx7ss66hdi

This happens to my screen randomly and can only be fixed by a gnome restart.

After that, it won't start again for a while.

The link includes videos of it happening. It happens on both monitors, and only to UI made by Ubuntu, so tops of windows and other UI like the dock

How can I stop it from happening, and what causes it?

Comment: Screen shots maybe instead of link to an outside site?

Comment: I cant really screenshot because they don't pick it up, and it only happens as the mouse is moving

Comment: you do not have phone with camera?